# Por que me da error el intentar actualizar una tabla mediante los datos de un datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SqlCommand insertar = new SqlCommand("update reparaciones set ([Codigo del Cliente]=@1,Nombres=@2,Apellidos=@3,Telefono=@4,Celular=@5,Dispositivo=@6,Modelo=@7,Color=@8,[Notas de Condiciones]=@9,[Reparaciones a Realizar]=@10,[Codigo Pieza]=@11,Descripcion=@11,Referencia=@12,Marca=@13,[Cantidad en Existencia]=@14,[Materiales de Reparacion]=@15,[Cantidad Vendida]=@16,[Compromiso de Entrega]=@17) where [Nombre de Imagen]=" + textBox1.Text, con);


            con.Open();

            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgv.Rows)
                {

                    insertar.Parameters.Clear();

                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column1"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column2"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column3"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column4"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column5"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@6", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column6"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@7", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column7"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@8", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column8"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@9", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column9"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@10", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column10"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@11", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column11"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@12", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column12"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@13", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column13"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@14", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column14"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@15", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column15"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@16", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column16"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@17", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column17"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@18", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column18"].Value));

                    insertar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Transaccion realizada con Exito.");



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error en la Transaccion." + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
```

error sqlexception.sqlclient. syntax near  '('.

Comment: Incluye el mensaje de error que recibes.

Comment: ya la edite @RobertoLeónOramas

Comment: En **SET** yo no he usado el **(** y cerrarlo **)** prueba eliminandolo de la sentencia.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas si tenias razon no eran necesarios , pero ahora me dice que en la condicion del where tengo unas comillas que no se cierran osea en el textbox1 de la condicion y no veo cuales serian a mi parecer estan bien cerrados

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas ya resolvi eso ahora tengo un error logico creo , lo voy a publicar en otro post